# Set JavaAgent in Java EE Maven project on Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-surefire-plugin, javaagents

In my Java EE Maven webapplication running on Tomcat I want to use http://sizeof.sourceforge.net or a comparable library requiring a `-javaagent:` call.

Using SO research, I have come to the following additions in my pom.xml:

1. for actually using the SizeOf library:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>net.sourceforge.sizeof</groupId>
       <artifactId>SizeOf</artifactId>
       <version>0.2.1</version>
       <type>jar</type>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. to make the -javaagent call

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.4</version>
       <configuration>
            <forkMode>once</forkMode>
            <argLine>
                -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/net/sourceforge/sizeof/SizeOf/0.2.1/SizeOf-0.2.1.jar"
            </argLine>
            <useSystemClassloader>true</useSystemClassloader>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```

Everything builds just fine. When I call a method using `SizeOf`, I'm getting an error Instrumentation is not set, indicating setting `-javaagent` failed.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: could you please add the output of "mvn -X clean install" ? (or whatever other maven invocation you use, with -X. there might be hints there

Comment: @radai Your question made me read -X output, learn a bunch and eventually figure out how to get what I want. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I was being a big noob concerning Maven and Surefire. The above configuration works as expected: It sets a javaagent for tests during buildtime. That's however, not what I wanted.*

Through my Netbeans IDE, I managed to set the -javaagent correctly as a VM Option on my TomEE/Tomcat server:

```
In Netbeans (OS X, 7.3): 
Tools > Servers > (your server) > Platform.
Fill in next to VM Options: -javaagent:/path/to/javaagent.jar
```

[image]

*P.S.: A Maven solution would be infinitely better. If you have one, please share it.*

Comment: how does maven start tomcat in your case?

Comment: found any maven solution ?